# .htaccess - RewriteRule append to end of URL after another RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess

I am successful executing 1 RewriteRule. Then I want a second RewriteRule to append onto the end of the resulting URL from the first RewriteRule.

I have the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On  # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule ^sports/football/?$ /sports/2018-19/sport_page.php?sport_id=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^2018-19?$ %{REQUEST_URI}&season_id=39 [L,QSA,R]
```

The first RewriteRule works - if "sports/football/" is found in the URL, it redirects as requested.

Then I want to check if "2018-19" exists in the URL, and if so, I want to append "&season_id=39" to the end of the results from the first ReWriteURL.

User goes to: http://domain/sports/football/2018-19/

First RewriteRule: http://domain/sports/2018-19/sport_page.php?sport_id=1

Second RewriteRule: http://domain/sports/2018-19/sport_page.php?sport_id=1&season_id=39

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your RewriteRule needs to check the full URL path .

```
RewriteRule ^sports/football/2018-19/?$ %{REQUEST_URI}?season_id=39 [L,R]
```

The rule above will generate a redirect loop error because the pattern and the destination path are identical. To solve this you can put the following `RewriteCond` right before the rule.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
```

The RewriteCond above  makes sure the the rule doesn't executive when the URI is `/sports/2018-19? query staring` .